# When using eb CLI is it possible to deploy without using git?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, elastic-beanstalk

Is there any way to use the AWS EB cli to just push the current state of my project rather than a specific commit?

Perhaps there are alternative values than `git` to the `sc` parameter in `config.yml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a file called .ebignore in your project root.

In the file, add the line

```
.git/
```

Now all deploys will use the .ebignore file and the current state of your projects instead of using git commits.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add

```
git init
git checkout -b master
git add .
git status
git commit -m "First Commit"
```

Every time that you add new code if you don`t want to add for commit could just use first deploy for files that you do make always new commits use command of` eb deploy --staged` Deploy files staged in the git index instead of the HEAD commit.